# LINQ group by month question

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm new to LINQ to SQL and I would like to know how to achieve something like this in LINQ:

```
        Month   Hires  Terminations   
        Jan      5       7
        Feb      8       8
        Marc     8       5
```

I've got this so far, and I think there is something wrong with it but I'm not sure:

```
from term1 in HRSystemDB.Terminations
group term1 by new { term1.TerminationDate.Month, term1.TerminationDate.Year } into grpTerm
select new HiresVsTerminationsQuery
{
  Date = Criteria.Period,
  TerminationsCount = grpTerm.Count(term => term.TerminationDate.Month == Criteria.Period.Value.Month),
  HiresCount = (from emp in HRSystemDB.Persons.OfType<Employee>()
               group emp by new { emp.HireDate.Month, emp.HireDate.Year } into grpEmp
               select grpEmp).Count(e => e.Key.Month == Criteria.Period.Value.Month)
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Showing us your database schema would help.

Comment: What's `Criteria.Period` and `Criteria.Period.Value.Month`?

Comment: What makes you feel unsure that it is right? Does it compile? Have you tried running it? Does it give the results you expect?

Comment: Criteria is a structure that contains some fields on which I filter my results (sorry for my english). In this case, Criteria.Period is a nullable datetime type, that's why I call Criteria.Period.Value. The query does compile, but it doesn't give the results as I expect them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not quite sure where does the `Criteria.Period` value come from in your sample query.

However I think you're trying to read both hires and terminations for all available months (and then you can easily filter it). Your query could go wrong if the first table (Termination) didn't include any records for some specified month (say May). Then the `select` clause wouldn't be called with "May" as the parameter at all and even if you had some data in the second table (representing Hires), then you wouldn't be able to find it.

This can be elegantly solved using the [Concat method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb737941.aspx) (see MSDN samples). You could select all termniations and all hires (into a data structure of some type) and then group all the data by month:

```
var terms = from t in HRSystemDB.Terminations 
            select new { Month = t.TerminationDate.Month, 
                         Year = term1.TerminationDate.Year,
                         IsHire = false };
var hires = from emp in HRSystemDB.Persons.OfType<Employee>() 
            select new { Month = emp.HireDate.Month, 
                         Year = emp.HireDate.Year 
                         IsHire = true };

// Now we can merge the two inputs into one
var summary = terms.Concat(hires);

// And group the data using month or year
var res = from s in summary 
          group s by new { s.Year, s.Month } into g
          select new { Period = g.Key, 
                       Hires = g.Count(info => info.IsHire),  
                       Terminations = g.Count(info => !info.IsHire) }
```

When looking at the code now, I'm pretty sure there is some shorter way to write this. On the other hand, this code should be quite readable, which is a benefit. Also note that it doesn't matter that we split the code into a couple of sub-queries. Thanks to lazy evalutation of LINQ to SQL, this should be executed as a single query.

Comment: This is a pretty good answer indeed. I didn't know about the concat method. I'll be experimenting with it later and posting my results. Thanks.

Comment: You saved my life. Worked great! Just what I was looking for. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it shorter but you can also try this version to see if it works better with your server.  I don't know exactly how these two answers turn into SQL statements. One might be better based on your indexs and such.

```
var terms = 
    from t in Terminations
    group t by new {t.Month, t.Year} into g
    select new {g.Key, Count = g.Count()};

var hires = 
    from p in Persons
    group p by new {p.Month, p.Year} into g
    select new {g.Key, Count = g.Count()};

var summary = 
    from t in terms
    join h in hires on t.Key equals h.Key
    select new {t.Key.Month, t.Key.Year, 
        Hires = h.Count, Terms = t.Count};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This versions works as long as there were any terminations or hires in the same month. If there were no hires or terminations in either of them no results will show up for that particular month, even if there was, say 2 hires but 0 terminations in May. I had to make a small correction, the group by (for my particular case) should be 
"group t by new { t.TerminationDate.Month, t.TerminationDate.Year } into g" and "group p by new { p.HireDate.Month, p.HireDate.Year } into g". Other than that I think it is a good answer. Thanks! +1 :-)