# How to get the current month date wise records using linq to sql?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I want to get the count of rows by date for each day this month, like this:

```
Date          count
1/03/2013     18
2/03/2013     41
28/03/2013    12
29/03/2013    14
```

How to write the query for that?

Comment: May be this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105208/linq-group-by-month-question

Comment: ??? Didn't get the question :(

Comment: if user wants to see january month  datewise  records then  how to write the linq to sql query?

Comment: I don't see any question here..

Comment: You want to get the number of occurences of the specific date?

Comment: number of occurences of all dates in particular month.

Answer (score 2):

So, I *assume* you have some table with a datetime field in which you have the date "1/03/2013" 18 times, meaning you have 18 rows in that table with that date.

Then you should get the count of each day of a month in a year by something like this:

```
var year = 2013;
var month = 3;
var q = from t in DBContext.TableName
        where t.DateField.Year == year && t.DateField.Month == month
        group t by t.DateField.Date
           into g
           select new
           {
               dateField = g.Key,
               countField = g.Count()
           };
```

See also the [LINQ to SQL Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/bb688085.aspx)

Comment: Getting Exception:Exception occured while validating  visitor. The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: @Venkat Is your "Date" field a real `DateTime` field? Are you using `t.Date.Date`? Is the name of the field really "Date" (I try to avoid naming fields to reserved words; hence `DateField`)? Did you by any chance adapt it differently to your needs?

Comment: we are maintaining date field as datetime in database.var query = (from t in cxt.visitor
                                 where t.singin.Year == year && t.singin.Month == month
                                 group t by t.singin.Date
                                  into g
                                select new
                                {
                                    dateField = g.Key,
                                    countField = g.Count()
                                }).ToList();  that was my query but getting above exception.

Comment: @Venkat huh, according to some other questions on SO that error seems to indicate, that the `signin` datetime field cannot be directly mapped to a database field. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584660/the-specified-type-member-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities-only-initializer or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036210/ef-4-the-specified-type-member-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities for example. Is it perhaps a custom property?